# Python variable assignment doesn't work

Tags: python

```
>>> header = 'subject'
>>> msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)   
>>> msg[header] = 'Test123'
>>> print msg[header]
=?UTF-8?B?UmU6IFtHQlMgU3lzdGVtYWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpb25dICMxMjogRS1NYWk=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?bCBCZW5hY2hyaWNodHVuZyBmw7xyIG5ldWUgVGlja2V0cyBlaW5yaWNodGVu?=
```

Why doesn't `msg[header]` contain `'Test123'`?

Comment: It should work fine. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: My problem is that `msg[header]` should contain 'Test123' after `msg[header] = 'Test123'`. Sorry if that wasn't obvious. Added it to the OP.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I would watch out for blanket statements in your title like "Python variable assignment doesn't work", since it has always worked for me :).  In the future, try being more specific, like "Python list assignment give surprising results with email module"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> __setitem__(name, val)
>
> Add a header to the message with field name name and value val. The field is appended to the end of the message’s existing fields.
>
> Note that this does not overwrite or delete any existing header with the same name. If you want to ensure that the new header is the only one present in the message with field name name, delete the field first, e.g.:

```
del msg['subject']
msg['subject'] = 'Python roolz!'
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message

Answer (score 2):

[http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.**setitem**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.__setitem__)

"Note that this does not overwrite or delete any existing header with the same name. If you want to ensure that the new header is the only one present in the message with field name name, delete the field first"